# AutoLayout two labels within a TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

I'm fairly new to iOS programming and probably don't understand the view hierarchy as well as I should and thus am failing to successfully get two labels within a custom table cell class I have created to autoresize properly. Namely the `"translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints"` property has me a little confused.

I am not using storyboards for this part of the code: I have a TableViewController where I create my own `tableView` in `viewDidLoad`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I init my own `TableViewCell` implementation.

The problem I'm having is that when I set `"setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints"` to `NO` for the table view and the UILabels I create then add my constraints, I get the following error:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSInternalInconsistencyException',` reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing `-layoutSubviews`. UITableView's implementation of `-layoutSubviews` needs to call super.'"
```

If I comment out the `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` lines, my app runs however I get the following warning about the constraints:

> "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.    Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
>   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints` that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the `UIView` property
>   `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`)"

Essentially what I want to do is to enter code here have the two labels flush against each other and for them to resize based on orientation/device (I will be setting a background colour on them so want them to look 'continuous')

Can anyone help me out and explain what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

My code for adding the labels is:

```
self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 30.0f)];
self.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0f];
self.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[self.nameLabel setText:@"Test"];
// [self.nameLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];
```

...

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = 
 NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel, summaryLabel);
NSArray *constraints = 
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[nameLabel][summaryLabel]-|" 
                                         options:0 
                                         metrics:nil 
                                           views:viewsDictionary];
```

Comment: What happens in your `updateConstraints` method and your `layoutSubviews` method? Are you calling `[super layoutSubviews]`?

Comment: hmm, according to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html   you should not call setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO   (see last paragraph of article)

Comment: Thanks @Evan, however I'm not overriding those methods in the custom cell class I have created, thus am not sure what the error is getting at..

Comment: @Yohst: I saw that, does that mean that I just can't use autolayout within a my own Table Cell implementation? I was hoping that I misunderstood that bit.

Comment: I don't think you should set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to no for the table view, only for the labels.

Comment: @rdelmar: That did indeed fix it! Thanks, I thought I had to specify translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for the container I was creating via custom means as well and not just its' contents. Thanks. Ps - if you translate your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm fairly new to ios programming and probably don't understand the
>   view hierarchy as well as I should and thus am failing to successfully
>   get two labels within a custom table cell class I have created to
>   autoresize properly. Namely the 
>   "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" property has me a
>   little confused.

Well, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is a property that is created by Apple to make the transition from `Autoresizing (Spring and Struts)` to `Autolayout` easier. Say, you had some `AutoresizingMasks` for your view and you just switched `Autolayout` ON without setting any constraints. Then your existing `AutoresizingMasks` will get converted into constraints which will hold the view in place. So, by default `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property is set to be YES. However, when you start adding constraints, in 90% cases they will conflict with the constraints that got created by converting your `AutoresizingMasks`. So, it is better to turn it off by setting `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`

In your code, the following might have been creating the problems:

---

- **The setting of `Frame`**

You should not set frames to objects which you will be adding constraints to. It's a paradigm shift. When you think in *Autolayout way*, frames are but effects of setting right constraints who combinedly determine the frame of the view in question.
So, please remove the frame setting.

`self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];` will suffice.

- **Setting proper constraints**

Your Code:

---

> ```
> NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel, summaryLabel);
> NSArray *constraints = 
>  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[nameLabel][summaryLabel]-|" 
>                                          options:0 
>                                          metrics:nil 
>                                            views:viewsDictionary];
> ```

- **NameLabel**

  - Now, the above constraints tells us the `nameLabel` should be **horizontally** (as you have not mentioned H: or V:) spaced "standard" distance (20px) from container, adjacent to the `summaryLabel`.
    But what about its Y position and Width and Height?
    So we need more constraints.
- **summaryLabel**

  - Same is applicable for `summaryLabel`.

So, lets define them properly:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =
NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel, summaryLabel);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[nameLabel(100)][summaryLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray *constraints1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[nameLabel(30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray *constraints2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[summaryLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray *constraints3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[nameLabel(==summaryLabel)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];


[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints1];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints2];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints3];
```

Now your views will look fine.

---

At any point of time, to check if your views are missing any constraints, pause the debugger and type the following in the console

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

it will show which of your views are having `AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT`

Also, remember in Storyboard/IB if the constraints are showing as "orange" colour, you need more constraints to define the objects position. Once you have added all necessary constraints, the constraints colours turn to "blue"

Answer (score 0):

First, are you adding constraints to self.contentView after creation?

Second, maybe your constraint set is insufficient for autolayout and it creates own constraints based on autoresizing mask. Try to add vertical constraints and width constraints for labels.